# Seeking geoprocessing tool to find all DTED tiles that intersect an Area of Interest (AOI)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, geoprocessing

Does a geoprocessing tool exist that can find all DTED tiles that intersect an AOI?

I have a area of interest represented by a polygon and DTED tiles (some of which intersect with the AOI).

Is there a tool that I can use to find which tiles intersect?

Comment: Doing this programmatically, I would iterate through the geodatabase's raster catalogs, performing spatial queries to return the DTED tiles that intersect.  I need to do the above, except with a model in ModelBuilder.

Comment: If you can perform the task programmatically, can you simply package a python script that performs the task as a tool and add it to your ModelBuilder model?

Comment: @AHigh I'm not familiar with Python.  I use ModelBuilder.

Comment: My code is written in C#

Comment: I've tried using the following C# to Python code converter, but it doesn't work for any set of code . . . http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-python/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this geoprocessing in QGIS by first making the image bounday of all DTED. This will convert all DTED to polygon shapefiles. Then run the spatial query for touches/intersects between your AOI and DTED polygon.

You need to download the Image boundary plugin for this.